# Run code after closing the modalDialogue box in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

After onclick of a button with ID "submitButton, I am trying to close the modaldialogue box and run a code in a function object.

```
var FuncObj = {
checker:checker
checker2:checker2
};
```

Following is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js">. 
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.padd5{
  padding: 5px 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="continue-button">
    <button class='blue' id="submitButton">Continue </button>
  </div>
  
</body>
<script>
$("#submitButton").click( 
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(close).runThatFunction(checker);`

function close(){
  google.script.host.close();
 }

</script>
</html>
```

And below is the code that renders the HTML, the HTML is rendered correctly but nothing happends when I click the button:

```
function test(functionName) {
if (condition1){
FuncObj[functionName]();
} 
if(condition2) {
  var html = HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile('unpaid')
  .evaluate()
  .getContent();
var finalHtml = HtmlService.createTemplate(html).evaluate().setWidth(300).setHeight(560);

SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
.showModalDialog(finalHtml, 'test');
} 
else {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Exhausted");  
}
}
```

Here is the call that function code:

```
function runThatFunction(functionName){ FuncObj[functionName]();}
```

The sequence of code is as below -

1. First "test(functionName)" from above will run.
2. If it goes in condition 2 then the modaldialogue box from the HTML will be shown to user
3. Once the user clicks on the button with ID "submitButton" the modal dialogue box should close and run the function that was passed as a parameter to test function in '1' above.

I am stuck on #2 from above sequence. Not able to close the modalDialogue box and run any function followed by it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between your HTML and your Google Apps Script. And also, I cannot understand about `Could I please get some help on running the appropriate function that is input to the first function?` and `But trying to use function object to make the code work with other functions as well.`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the question. Hopefully, it is clear now. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: Why are you making the `finalHtml` rather than simply calling `.setWidth(300).setHeight(560)` on `html`?

Comment: Have you tried logging `html` and `finalHtml` after each one evaluates? Are they both generated as you would expect?

Answer (score 0):

To run code after closing, add the code that you want to run after `google.script.host.close();`. Please bear in mind that this only will work the closing is done by calling the `close()` function.